# Circular Double Linked List Infinite Loop

Tags: java

My CS professor asked us to develop our own Java program using circular linked lists. My project is to add or delete names (of type String) from a circular list. So far, my add methods work perfectly; however, my removeNode() method does not work and does not remove the desired element. It also goes on an infinite loop and I have tried so many pieces of code and neither of them work. 
My remove method is the following:

```
public E removeNode(E nodeToBeDeleted)
{
    Node<E> nodeFound = findNode(nodeToBeDeleted);

    if(nodeFound != null)
    {
        nodeFound.prev.next = nodeFound.next;
        nodeFound.next.prev = nodeFound.prev;
        size--;
        return nodeFound.data;  
    }
    return null;
}
```

basically, the findNode() searches for the node whose data is equal to the String plugged in as a parameter, but when I call the outputList() method, which returns a String representation of the current nodes on screen, it goes on infinite loop.

The outputList method is:

```
public void outputList()
{   
    Node<E> position = head;
    do 
    {
        System.out.print(position.data + " ==> ");
        position = position.next;

    } while((position != null) && (position.next != position));
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

The Node class is:

```
    static class Node<E> {

    /** The data value. */
    private E data;
    /** The link to the next node. */
    private Node<E> next = null;
    /** The link to the previous node. */
    private Node<E> prev = null;

    private Node(E dataItem) {
        data = dataItem;
    }


    private Node(E newData, Node<E> nodeRef)
    {
        data = newData;
        next = nodeRef;
    }

    private Node(Node<E> prevRef, E newData)
    {
        data = newData;
        prev = prevRef;
    }

   //set next link
    private Node(Node<E> newData, Node<E> nodeRef)
    {
        data = (E) newData;
        next = nodeRef;
    }
} //end class Node
```

Comment: Does it remove the wrong node? if so which one?

Comment: No, it does not remove either the String parameter or any other node. When I call the outputList() method, it goes on an infinite loop and crashes..

Comment: also according to geekviewpoint.com when you traverse a circular linkedlist you have to break when `if (tmp.right == head) {
        break;
      }` see www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bst/to_circular_doubly_linked_list_iterative#tabs-2

Comment: now I get a NullPointerException message..

Comment: @jv0006 Then **debug** it. Java exceptions tell you where they happen, and moreover it's really easy in any IDE to set breakpoints and check whether values are what you want them to be!

Comment: post your node class so we can see why delete fails

Comment: I've tried debugging it. But when I set the break point at the outputList() method, the Debug takes me to the line where - private E data; - is located. The Node class is above

Answer (score 4):

```
while((position != null) && (position.next != position))
```

This should really be:

```
while((position != null) && (position.next != head))
```

Imagine if you have a singleton - the absolute base case for traversal.  `head` and `position` will both be pointing to it when you start, and when you wish to advance, `position` will refer to the same place as `head` once again.  This will continue *ad infinitum*.

The iteration must stop when you've reached your starting point once again.

Comment: this seems an excellent approach; however, I continue having the same problem, it continues printing out the same list over and over again!

Comment: I am trying to figure out what's wrong.. whenever I try to add a new node into the list, I don't get any problem at all

Comment: From the context of your question, this would address your infinite loop while printing out nodes.  If you have another question in regards to bugs in your problem, they would be better suited to another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(position.next != head)
```

I think checking above condition is enough for  Doubly Circular LinkedList.